# Match FrameLayout height with ImageView in it

Tags: android, height, imageview, android-framelayout

In my layout I have a FrameLayout which contains 2 ImageViews. One ImageView is shown at a time and the change between ImageViews is done through 3D Rotation animation.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/animContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/malware" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/browsing"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

The problem with my xml is that it leaves some empty space above and below the ImageView in the FrameLayout even though I have not specified any top or bottom margin/padding to it.
The ImageViews I'm using in the FrameLayout are of equal heights.
I want the height of the FrameLayout to be exactly same as the height of the ImageViews within it.
How do I achieve this?
Thank you.

EDIT:
Another thing I have observed is that in landscape mode the empty space is added to the left and right of the ImageViews  and the width of the FrameLayout does not match with the width of the ImageViews.
How can have the FrameLayout width and height same as that of the ImageViews?

Comment: set scaletype of imageview to fitxy

Comment: Did you try android:scaleType="fitXY" in you ImageView xml?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But android:scaleType="fitXY" didn't help me much. By doing this the height of my ImageView increased to match with the height of the FrameLayout. And so my Images got stretched vertically. I wish to match the height of the FrameLayout with the height of my ImageViews

Comment: @Zeba, I'm facing the exact same problem right now. The FrameLayout is bigger than it's content. Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use android:adjustViewBounds="true" -> in your ImageView's ... This will resize the imageview to the image inside and hopefully fix your problem.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds

Comment: thank you for your answer, but android:adjustViewBounds="true" did not affect my layout at all. The height of the FrameLayout still does not match with the height of the ImageViews within it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, in mine I had to place an image in the right hand corner for the delete icon but had to jump through hoops to get the edge of the X to line up with the top of the photo.  fitCenter would create whitespace on top and bottom.  fitStart worked like a charm.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/front_right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="imageEditClicked"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/front_right_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_black_xout" />

</FrameLayout>
```